Why does iPython choose an earlier version of Python?
I'm trying to upgrade from Python 3.11 to 3.12 and running into some problems, illustrated by iPython's unwillingness to go with me.  I'm doing all this on an Arm Macbook Air with Python installed by Homebrew, in case that matters.  Here's a copy of my Terminal activity, followed by my understanding of what's happening.  Any corrections are appreciated.  The *** strings are for a bit of security, replacing pathnames (newlines inserted for readability).
(ds) *** % python --version
Python 3.12.3
(ds) *** % ipython
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:937: 
UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, 
please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
 warn(
Python 3.11.9 (main, Apr  2 2024, 08:25:04) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.24.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print (sys.version)
3.11.9 (main, Apr  2 2024, 08:25:04) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)]

In [3]: ^D

After getting the UserWarning the first time, I ran "pip install ipython"
AND "pipx install ipython" but I continue to get that UserWarning.  I did pipx because pip told me the requirements were already satisfied.  All of this activity is within the "ds" virtual environment.
I first encountered this when a "from sklearn import..." failed in a jupyter
notebook and did not fail from a "python" REPL.  I have the feeling that
solving the ipython problem will get me a long way toward the original objective.

So, it seems ipython was installed directly to the user level homebrew python, not inside any environment. That is generally inadvisable (basically, it is inadvisable to install anything there). IPython is just a python library, it needs to be installed for whichever interpreter/environment you are using. Now, the problem seems to be that when you try to use pip, you are finding the pip associated with the user-level homebrew python, not your environment. that maybe is due to how you created your environment. I can only speculate. that seems to be the problem. what does which pip show?

but, if python is resolving to the interpreter in the environment, as it seems to be, then you can use python -m pip install ipython.

"I first encountered this when a "from sklearn import..." failed in a jupyter notebook and did not fail from a "python" REPL. " so, I suggest installing jupyter for each environment and using that jupyter installation to run notebooks with that particular interpreter/environment. although, you can have a jupyter installation in one environment work with various other interpreters/environments (even other languages) by making them "kernels" but I've personally avoided that in my personal environments on my laptop
